# Mongodb fail to start after changing the mongodb.conf

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new on Mongodb server. I'm trying to create a replica set on it. But when i change the configuration on the mongod.conf, my mongodb service is not working or running anymore. Any idea how to solve this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share the error you are facing along with the MongoDB configuration file.

Only after seeing that, I can help you with your issue.

You can also view the configuration file options here,
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before making any changes to mongod.conf file stop the serivce and after making the changes start it.